Garage apartment flooding in left front corner
So we made our garage into an apartment for our grandson and his girlfriend. In the front left corner it’s flooding. We pull the floor up twice dried it out quickly my husband then dug a trench or whatever you call it and poured concrete there where it’s flooding on the outside of the garage, but it’s like the water is going underground and coming up. What can we do? This is so frustrating. It did it again this morning so we’re gonna have to pull the floor up once again.

Pictures will be nice.  You stop water from coming in by either sealing on the outside or removed excess water from around/under the building, with drainage pipes or a sump pump if coming from underneath.  make sure the ground is slope down away from the building and any downspouts carry water away and not dump by the wall/s.

Was the garage not flooding   before you made it into an apartment?

Have you checked out the gutters and drains yet? Often basement water problems are actually because you're not keeping the water away from the foundation.

Where your home would have a vapor barrier to prevent ground moisture from coming up, the garage floor does not and the cement acts like a sponge.   You need to do as others suggested and prevent any water from coming near the slab. However you may find it necessary to seal the garage floor with a good waterproofer or waterproof paint, or something like RedGuard or Aquaseal prior to putting any finished flooring down.

Ensure that surface drainage runs away from the garage.
